# html embedded conditional if statements in php

Tags: php, html, if-statement, conditional-statements

I feel like this should be pretty simple, but I'm not getting the results that I want. I have an email signup form that displays across all my websites. If they happen to visit my website with the store code `ama_br` the email signup disappears. That is fine and that works. My `elseif` statement is a different form than the one that is displayed across all store views and I want this new form to only appear when it's store code `ama_ca`. It does not work for me and I don't see anything wrong with my code. Please help. Thank you.

```
            <?php if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() != "ama_br"):?>
                <ul>
                    <li><?php echo $this->__('Email Sign Up')?></li>
                    <li>
                        <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('email_preferences')?>" method="get" id="newsletter-validate-detail">
                            <input name="email" type="text" id="newsletter" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Enter Email address')?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Enter Email address')?>' class="required-entry validate-email">
                            <button class="submit">+</button>
                            <input type="hidden" name="source" value="nt">
                        </form>
                    </li>
                    <li class="footer-promo"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_promo')?></li>
                </ul>

            <?php elseif (Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() == "ama_ca"):?>
                <ul>
                    <li><?php echo $this->__('Email Sign Up')?></li>
                    <li>
                <form method="post" action="http://enews.******.com/q/9MNK4U4iV9Mutb9YzTxF2zRWDIPgKoX0F0" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                        <input type="hidden" name="crvs" value="6hZNXcISD79ac2Empmsr2az_B3Qc5osTNmkOdNHleqhPIYmsxEOe6PbgaUo-3WBn_Vbgorrbk4qjekx7w4tljA">
                        <input type="hidden" name="CheckBox.Source.ca_footer" value="on">
                        <input name="email" type="text" id="newsletter" placeholder="Enter Email address" title="Enter Email address' class=" required-entry="">
                        <input type="hidden" id="submit" value="Sign Up">
                        </form>
                    </li>
                    <li class="footer-promo"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_promo')?></li>
                </ul>
            <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: logic. only ONE block of an `if` will execute. since you're doing a `!=`  test in the first one, then `'ama_ca' != 'ama_br'` is TRUE, and that block executes, skipping ENTIRELLY the `== 'ama_ca'` one that follows.

Comment: Put the check for `ama_ca` first.

Comment: @ thismethod refer to my answer it will resolve your query

Comment: Thanks @MarcB, i wasn't aware of how that logic was working. Thank you. *noted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description** 
You have done every thing right but you just miss the trick look carefully on your if statement Logic that is if your Code not equals to **ama_br** that is it can be equal to **ama_ca** so it will show the form in if statement for **ama_ca** as well as on any other string from **ama_br** so the form you are trying to show on Code equals to **ama_ca** is not showing. Try one of the following it will resolve your query.

**Code**

```
        <?php if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() == "ama_ca"): ?>
          <ul>
            <li><?php echo $this->__('Email Sign Up') ?></li>
            <li>
            <form method="post" action="http://enews.******.com/q/9MNK4U4iV9Mutb9YzTxF2zRWDIPgKoX0F0" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <input type="hidden" name="crvs" value="6hZNXcISD79ac2Empmsr2az_B3Qc5osTNmkOdNHleqhPIYmsxEOe6PbgaUo-3WBn_Vbgorrbk4qjekx7w4tljA">
            <input type="hidden" name="CheckBox.Source.ca_footer" value="on">
            <input name="email" type="text" id="newsletter" placeholder="Enter Email address" title="Enter Email address' class=" required-entry="">
            <input type="hidden" id="submit" value="Sign Up">
            </form>
            </li>
           <li class="footer-promo"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_promo') ?></li>
         </ul>

        <?php elseif (Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() != "ama_br"): ?>
          <ul>
            <li><?php echo $this->__('Email Sign Up') ?></li>
            <li>
              <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('email_preferences') ?>" method="get" id="newsletter-validate-detail">
              <input name="email" type="text" id="newsletter" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Enter Email address') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Enter Email address') ?>' class="required-entry validate-email">
                   <button class="submit">+</button>
              <input type="hidden" name="source" value="nt">
              </form>
              </li>
              <li class="footer-promo"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_promo') ?></li>
             </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

**OR**

```
       <?php if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() != "ama_br" && Mage::app()- >getStore()->getCode() != "ama_ca"): ?>
          <ul>
           <li><?php echo $this->__('Email Sign Up') ?></li>
            <li>
            <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('email_preferences') ?>" method="get" id="newsletter-validate-detail">
            <input name="email" type="text" id="newsletter" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Enter Email address') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Enter Email address') ?>' class="required-entry validate-email">
                   <button class="submit">+</button>
                   <input type="hidden" name="source" value="nt">
            </form>
       </li>
       <li class="footer-promo"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_promo') ?></li>
      </ul>

      <?php elseif (Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() == "ama_ca"): ?>
      <ul>
          <li><?php echo $this->__('Email Sign Up') ?></li>
      <li>
        <form method="post" action="http://enews.******.com/q/9MNK4U4iV9Mutb9YzTxF2zRWDIPgKoX0F0" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <input type="hidden" name="crvs" value="6hZNXcISD79ac2Empmsr2az_B3Qc5osTNmkOdNHleqhPIYmsxEOe6PbgaUo-3WBn_Vbgorrbk4qjekx7w4tljA">
            <input type="hidden" name="CheckBox.Source.ca_footer" value="on">
            <input name="email" type="text" id="newsletter" placeholder="Enter Email address" title="Enter Email address' class=" required-entry="">
            <input type="hidden" id="submit" value="Sign Up">
        </form>
    </li>
       <li class="footer-promo"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_promo')  ?></li>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ahmer. I'm using the first answer based on how the logic works and less code.